# New to using Axios, need sample snippet

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios

How Do i implement Login using Axios so i can get the username and password i have done this with Fetch, but for some reason, even after setting CORS, Normally I use Fetch, But i have not tried out with Axios.
This is my code for Fetch which works fine, which is supposed to work, but somehow returns problems in the long run..

```
  login = () =>{
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const body = { email, password };
    fetch('http://localhost:5001/auth/sign_in',{
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers:{
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-type':'application/json'
      },
      body:body
    }).then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=>{
      if(responseJson.message ==='OK'){
        localStorage.setItem('token',responseJson.token);
        <Navigate to="/dashboard" />
      }
    })
  }
```

How Do I convert this into Axios?

Comment: https://axios-http.com/

Answer (score 0):

Fetch worked after all. I had to install `CORS` on the REST API (Backend) and after that everything appeared to be fine